# How to share sessions between two oracle middleware environments

Tags: oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-ucm

I have two middlewares in the same machine (just for now, can be different machines). In the first middleware I have a Content Server (UCM) in order to store some documents, in the second middleware I have a web application that connects to the UCM (using RIDC) in order to list some documents according to some search criteria.

The web application also puts a link button with the URI to that document in the UCM viewer, but, when a I click the button it opens the Content Server login page... And I need that users can view documents without the need to login again. Both middlewares share the same active directory in order to have the same users.

I tried to use a trust certificate in both weblogics but that doesn't work. So, how can I have links to pages to UCM Viewer in other middleware without login at that middleware again?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.

1. You could setup a SSO option such as OAM or SAML.
2. You could fetch the content item using RIDC and stream it to the end user. This way all the authentication is already taken care of using RIDC.

http://jonathanhult.com/blog/2012/12/ridc-examples/

Comment: Hi, I've seen that feature in RIDC before but I really need to show the document through the UCM Viewer because of some security configurations provided by another developer and this is a requirement of this project... I'll try your first suggestion, do you have any more info about that one?, thank you

Comment: Use a SSO solution between the two applications.